# (C#) Unity2D - Animation Fighting my Character's Movement?

Tags: c#, animation, position, unity-game-engine

I'd like to thank you in advance for helping me with this issue.

I have a player that consists of three part:
The body
The head
and the Arm

All three of these are individual sprites.

I have grouped them all under one Empty GameObject that I named "Player"

I have then added an animation on the "Player" GameObject that changes the Y position from **0 to 0.022**, and then from **0.022 back to 0**.
This create a nice little hover animation where the character bounces up and down.

The animation works perfectly fine!

However, I also have a script attached to the "Player" object, this script is called "PlayerController".

In PlayerController I change the player's x Position if they hold down A (for leftwards movement) or D (for rightwards movement).

```
protected bool facingRight = true;
float xPos = 0;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        xPos += 0.01f;
        if (!facingRight)
        {
            Flip();
        }
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        xPos -= 0.01f;

        if (facingRight)
        {
            Flip();
        }
    }

    gameObject.transform.position = new Vector2(xPos, transform.position.y);

}

protected void Flip()
{
    facingRight = !facingRight;
    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
    theScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = theScale;
}
```

When I hold A or D, the character refuses to move. However he does flip correctly.

I personally think my animation is fighting the script, and that the animation has a higher priority than the script...?

[Here's a video of me explaining my issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j52KOa-Gvvo&feature=youtu.be)

(Not sure if videos are generally accepted in this community or not. If not, then I apologize)

If you guys could please help me understand what is happening and how to correct it I would be extremely grateful.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem after hours of tinkering.

Turns out the solution was simple:

All I had to do was structure my player like this:

- Player (Empty GameObject)

  - PlayerAssembly (Body, Head, and Arm's parent)

    - Body Parts (Body, Head, Arm)

and then put the script, rigidBody2D, and collider on "Player".

Then put the animator on "PlayerAssembly".

[image: Image of Hierarchy]